# Regex to ignore precise match

Tags: regex

I want to match everything that starts with & and ends with ; however ignore if and only if string is `&lt;`

So I've done this `&(.+?)[^lt];` but the problem is it ignores `&foolt;` what am I doing wrong here?

Here is my test case:

```
&asdas;
&asdasdqwe;
&ltasd;
&lt;
&asdasdlt;
&foolt;
```

I expect nothing but the 4th one to be ignored. I test it using http://www.regexr.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take apart your regex `&(.+?)[^lt];`:

- `&` an ampersand
- `(.+?)` then one or more characters (reluctantly).
- `[^lt]` then one character, anything but 'l' or 't'.
- `;` then a semicolon

Which isn't quite right.  You can check for the 'lt;' with a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), right after the ampersand, like:

```
&(?!lt;).+?;
```

- `&` an ampersand
- `(?!lt;)` be sure that we don't match `lt;` from this position
- `.+?` then one or more characters (reluctantly).
- `;` then a semicolon

Comment: For some reason I'm getting `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 1` in Java with this expression

Comment: @SarpKaya There are no capturing groups in the expression I've given.  You might be looking for: `&(?!lt;)(.+?);` which will capture everything between the & and the ; in group 1.

Answer (score 2):

You regex is using a negated character class `[^lt]` which means "not `l` and not `t`, 1 occurrence exactly".

Here is the regex that will match what you need:

```
(?!^&lt;$)&(\S+);
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dT2rI8/5) is here.

`(?!^&lt;$)` makes sure the whole string/line is not `&lt;`

Comment: I updated my question, second one doesn't match with anything at all, first one matches with `&lt;` (and all the other examples)

Comment: Why `(?=(?!^&lt;$))` instead of just `(?!^&lt;$)`?

Comment: @femtoRgon: Bad habit, sorry :)

Comment: I don't know why that link works on regex101. I am using the same expression in Java as well (with `String.replaceAll()` method and getting the same issues)

Comment: Use `/gm` options on regexr.com. Click the `Flags` button on the right and select `multiline`. And in Java, you can use inline option `(?m)` in the beginning of a regex string.